# Is it possible to execute a remote command via SCP in the same way as SSH?

Tags: ssh, scp, combine, remote-execution

I want to embed a remote execution command in an `SCP` command. Is that possible?

It will save having to execute an `SCP` command first, then executing an SSH command on the transferred fiies.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You might be better doing it the other way around - i.e. transferring the files as part of the ssh session, then executing the cmds as part of the same ssh.

See here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/copy-over-ssh-and-execute-commands-in-one-session

I really don't think scp has the capability you're after but you can 'emulate' the same result over ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to avoid running scp followed by ssh? Is it because connecting is slow? If so you might want to try ssh multiplexing:

With multiplexing you can connect once, then any future ssh or scp commands will reuse the existing connection.

Here are some links that explain ssh multiplexing:

- http://www.symkat.com/ssh-tips-and-tricks-you-need
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing